# What's a clean way to access a variable in my anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, parse-platform

I've found duplicates of my question, but none of them work for me and I couldn't find a clean answer. I've tried passing in the score to another method to set the score and also passing in the object to another method to set the score and neither of them work. Score is "0" every time regardless of what I do. What should I do? Right now I have:

```
public class Score {
    private int score;

    // this is part of my onCreate method but I shortened it for simplication

    // get android id
    android_id =  Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), 
                                   Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    // set score
    queryScore(android_id);
    // print score
    System.out.println(score);

    // end onCreate method

    public void queryScore(String android_id) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidGame");
        query.whereEqualTo("androidID", android_id);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
              public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    score = object.getInt("playerScore");
                    // (1) setScore(score);
                    // (2) setScore(object);
                } else {
                }
              }
            });
    }

    // DOESN'T WORK (1)
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    // DOESN'T WORK (2)
    public void setScore(ParseObject po) {
        score = po.getInt("playerScore");
    }     
}
```

turns out, `query.getFirstInBackground()` is an asynchronous call. `query.find()` would give you the same functionality without being an async call

Comment: Just glancing at it, it seems like it should work. Can you create a [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) with only JDK classes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how to create a SSCCE and it seems like something more complicated than what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this issue has to do with threads. It looks like your `query.getFirstInBackground` runs another thread which calls the `done` method when it's finished. If that's the case, then I don't think you'd have access to the same instance of `score` when you go to set the value.

One solution to this would be to make `score` a static member and then operate on that static member from within `done`.

Comment: This is what I suspected as well, but when I changed `private int score` to `private static int score` and both with/without changing `score = object.getInt("playerScore")` to `Score.score = object.getInt("playerScore")` (am I supposed to do this?), it still returns 0 for score

Comment: I updated my original post with the link from the parse forums. However, I'm still running into problems as my last comment on here suggests

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out, but thanks for pointing me towards the right direction

Comment: @ErmiasAsghedom Glad to hear you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue is changing a class member value from an inner anonymous class, I took the liberty to modify your code to a smaller, simpler example.

```
public class Score {

    private int score;

    private class B{
        public void done(){
        }
    }

    public Object queryScore(final HashMap<String, Integer> a) {

        B b =  new B() {
            public void done() {
                score = a.get("playerScore");
                setScore(score);//works
                setScore(a);//works
            }
        };
        return b;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void setScore(HashMap<String, Integer> po) {
        score = po.get("playerScore");
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Score s = new Score();
        HashMap<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        a.put("playerScore", 3);
        B b = (B) s.queryScore(a);
        b.done();
        System.out.println(s.getScore());
    }
}
```

in the example above - both `setScore()` methods works.
You should look in `getFirstInBackground()` and see if `done()` is getting called on the passed object!

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm using parse.com as my backend and I have to follow its API: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/class-use/ParseObject.html